# Lessen Space between content and footer

Tags: html, css, laravel, bootstrap-4

I am making a homepage for a press release.

There is a big space between my `content` and my `footer`, which I don't want. I tried using `margin-top: 0px` in css, but that doesn't help. I also tried a lot of other `margin` and `padding` settings, but I just can't get the result I am looking for.

Could somebody help? Thanks in advance.

**Here is an image of my website:**

[image]

**Here is my code:**

```
@extends('Press_Release_Views.layout')
    @section('content')
    <img src="/Picture/background.jpg">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="recent_border">
    <h4 class="Recent">Recent News Releases</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="/Picture/sample1.jpg" alt="Lights" class="sample1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <p class="october">October 31,2017</p>
    <p class="lorem">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy </p>
     <p class="paragraph1">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="border">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="/Picture/sample2.jpg" alt="Lights" class="sample2">

    </div>
    <p class="October1">October 12,2017</p>
    <p class="lorem1">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy </p>
    <div class="border1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="/Picture/sample2.jpg" alt="Lights" class="sample3">

    </div>
    <p class="October2">October 12,2017</p>
    <p class="lorem2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy </p>
    <div class="col-md-3 thumbnail3">
            <img src="/Picture/sample3.jpg" alt="Lights" class="sample4">

    </div>
    <p class="October3">October 12,2017</p>
    <p class="lorem3">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy </p>

    <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="/Picture/sample3.jpg" alt="Lights" class="sample5">

    </div>
    <p class="October4">October 12,2017</p>
    <p class="lorem4">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy </p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger button_red">Browse All Recent Release</button>
    <div class="News_border">
    <h4 class="more_news">More News</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="/Picture/sample4.jpg" alt="Lights" class="sample6">

    </div>
    <p class="October5">October 12,2017</p>
    <p class="lorem5">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy </p>

    <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="/Picture/sample4.jpg" alt="Lights" class="sample7">

    </div>
    <p class="October6">October 12,2017</p>
    <p class="lorem6">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy </p>

    <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="/Picture/sample4.jpg" alt="Lights" class="sample8">

    </div>
    <p class="October7">October 12,2017</p>
    <p class="lorem7">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy </p>

    <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="/Picture/sample4.jpg" alt="Lights" class="sample9">

    </div>
    <p class="October8">October 12,2017</p>
    <p class="lorem8">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy </p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger button_red1">Browse All Recent Release</button>
    </div>  
    @endsection
```

Comment: do margin-bottom:0 on the content, and don't paste the blade post the parsed html and the **css**

Comment: I already fix it :) thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 3):

Target the div and use: `margin-bottom: 0px;`

Comment: you mean  `margin-bottom:0;` as the comment  i provided